# Error compiling Qt5 with openssl linked

Tags: qt, openssl

My head will explode soon... I want to compile qt with -openssl-linked so the openssl libraries get linked into the qt libraries. I already tried many options and my output when compiling is always:

```
ssl/qsslcertificate_openssl.cpp: In function ‘uint qHash(const QSslCertificate&, uint)’:
ssl/qsslcertificate_openssl.cpp:63:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘X509 {aka struct x509_st}’
     return qHashBits(x509->sha1_hash, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, seed);
                          ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/openssl/crypto.h:131:0,
             from /usr/local/include/openssl/comp.h:59,
             from /usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:148,
             from ../../include/QtNetwork/5.5.1/QtNetwork/private/../../../../../src/network/ssl/qsslcontext_openssl_p.h:53,
             from ../../include/QtNetwork/5.5.1/QtNetwork/private/qsslcontext_openssl_p.h:1,
             from ssl/qsslsocket_p.h:55,
             from ssl/qsslsocket_openssl_p.h:63,
             from ssl/qsslsocket_openssl_symbols_p.h:64,
             from ssl/qsslcertificate_openssl.cpp:35:
/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:160:16: note: forward declaration of ‘X509 {aka struct x509_st}’
 typedef struct x509_st X509;
```

I compiled openssl and tried compiling qt passing my compiled libraries:

```
OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/opt/openssl_build/lib -lssl -lcrypto' ./configure -prefix /opt/qt5.5.1_linux_staticssl -opensource -confirm-license -release -nomake examples -nomake tests -static -openssl -no-opengl -no-libpng -no-pulseaudio -no-linuxfb -no-gif -no-gstreamer -no-gtkstyle -no-directfb -no-gui -no-eglfs -no-glib -I /opt/openssl_build/include/openssl -L /opt/openssl_build/lib -no-xcb
```

I know the error seems to be loading the old openssl libraries but I already tried changing that path so it can't find them and force it to load the new ones. 
I don't know what else to do. The Qt version is 5.5.1 openssl 1.0.1 and g++ 5.2.

Comment: Where did you get OpenSSL from? In branch OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable (e.g. release 1.0.1r), `struct x509_st` is defined in the public header `x509.h`. On the current master it is defined in an internal header `internal/x509_int.h`, which is likely to cause the problem.

Comment: It worked. I was compiling the git's master branch of openssl, when I compiled the 1.0.1 and tried qt with it worked. I had to temporarily change the path to the system's openssl libraries so that qt had to use the 1.0.1 I compiled.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I had to build Qt with the openssl version 1.0.1, don't know if it work with the 1.0.2. I had to change the path of the system's openssl libraries so that Qt was forced to use the ones I made. 
Lines to compile openssl running at the source's directory:

```
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl_build_stable -shared
make
make test
sudo make install
```

My conf line for Qt:

```
OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/opt/openssl_build_stable/lib -lssl -lcrypto' ./configure -prefix /opt/qt5.5.1_linux_staticssl -opensource -confirm-license -release -nomake examples -nomake tests -static -openssl-linked -I /opt/openssl_build_stable/include/openssl -L /opt/openssl_build_stable/lib
```

Thanks to simon-warta

Comment: It should also work with 1.0.2 according to this nice documentation: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes (See 5.1 "No longer works -> Qt")

Comment: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt5.git/log/ (version 5.11)
 one of the commit says  
Provisioning: Update openssl to version 1.0.2pv5.11.35.11.3
for version 5.8 found nothing about ssl version.

Comment: This did not help me. I try to build Telegram Desktop at Ubuntu 18.04.1, Telegram build wants openssl 1.0.1 stable, but the system seems to have OPENSSL_1_1_0. The build with or without your method fails with messages like `invalid use of incomplete type ‘X509 {aka struct x509_st}’`.

Comment: My system has apt packages libssl1.0-dev (apt version 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.2), libssl1.0.0 (apt version 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.2) and libssl1.1 (apt version 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.3).

Answer (score 4):

Try `./configure -no-openssl`

to bypass openssl altogether, in case you don't need your paraView to talk to another machine.