# Qt 5.5.1 compiling on Archlinux results with error: this use of "defined" may not be portable [-Wexpansion-to-defined]

Tags: linux, qt, gcc, makefile, qmake

I need to compile qt-5.5 for building various applications. 
Qt provides instruction to accomplish this [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) , but following the steps provided, results in a `make` error.

**Note:** I attempted searching for a solution of this `make` warning without success, however, may be someone else experienced this problem.

System used:

- **Archlinux** (Linux arch-desktop 4.9.77-1-lts #1 SMP Wed Jan 17 12:59:05 CET 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
- **Qt** 5.5.1
- **OpenSSL** 1.0.2g
- **GCC** (GCC) 7.2.1 20171224

**Steps taken:**

OS Installation:

- During ArchLinux installation, I installed development packages with `pacstrap /mnt/point/here base base-devel`, see [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Installing_packages) for more info

Post Installation:

- Downloaded Qt 5.5.1 from [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.5/5.5.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1.tar.gz.mirrorlist)
- Downloaded appropriate OpenSSL 1.0.2g (same found in Ubuntu distributions as this is my target platform) found [here](https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/o/openssl/)
- Installing this OpenSSL version will break dependencies, so I extracted it to `/opt/lib/openssl/`, and placed the `lib`, `bin`, `share` folders in the root folder mentioned above.
- extracted Qt-5.5.1
- ran `OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/opt/lib/openssl/lib/ -lssl -lcrypto'; ./configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -confirm-license -openssl-linked -prefix /opt/qt-5.5.1`
  (This sets the openssl library location to use for configuring. Then I link the openssl libraries and configure Qt-5.5.1 to install to `/opt/qt-5.5.1`)
- This results in an appropriate output of abilities which Qt will have once installed, amongst which `OpenSSL` is found

Finally, `make`ing with 
- `make -j 8`

This takes a while eventually throwing the error:

```
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qlist.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:43,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/io/qiodevice.h:39,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qiodevice.h:1,
                 from io/qfiledevice.h:37:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:169:1: error: this use of "defined" may not be portable [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
 #if QT_SUPPORTS(UNSHARABLE_CONTAINERS)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2660: .obj/header_qtextcodec.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2436: .obj/header_qsequentialanimationgroup.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:3127: .obj/header_qlibraryinfo.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1855: .obj/header_qabstractanimation.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1964: .obj/header_qanimationgroup.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2075: .obj/header_qparallelanimationgroup.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2186: .obj/header_qpauseanimation.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2573: .obj/header_qvariantanimation.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2325: .obj/header_qpropertyanimation.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:3714: .obj/header_qbuffer.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:3825: .obj/header_qdatastream.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:4202: .obj/header_qdiriterator.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:4079: .obj/header_qdir.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:4313: .obj/header_qfile.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:4422: .obj/header_qfiledevice.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:3958: .obj/header_qdebug.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/cybex/qt-5.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/src/corelib'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:142: sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/cybex/qt-5.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:46: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cybex/qt-5.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase'
make: *** [Makefile:73: module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

If you suspect that the fancy 'tricks' using OpenSSL may be causing the problem. No, since I tried it using my OpenSSL-1.1 install which resulted in the same issue. The older OpenSSL version is to be compatible with the older Qt version (still supported in Ubuntu systems)

Any thoughts on what may cause the problem?

**UPDATE**

After apply the suggested change, as mentioned by `@ssbssa`, I was able to proceed further with compiling, but still ran into an issue.

I used the following configure command on a fresh source extract:

`OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/opt/lib/openssl/lib/ -lssl -lcrypto'; ./configure -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -confirm-license -openssl-linked -prefix /opt/qt-5.5.1`

I received the following error output.

```
//...

g++ -o .obj/moc_qopengltimerquery.o .moc/moc_qopengltimerquery.cpp
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qcontiguouscache.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h:46,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qdebug.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/math3d/qgenericmatrix.h:38,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qgenericmatrix.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/math3d/qquaternion.h:37,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qquaternion.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/math3d/qmatrix4x4.h:39,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qmatrix4x4.h:1,
                 from .moc/../opengl/qopenglshaderprogram.h:45,
                 from .moc/moc_qopenglshaderprogram.cpp:9:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qcontiguouscache.h:99:1: warning: this use of "defined" may not be portable [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
 #if QT_SUPPORTS(UNSHARABLE_CONTAINERS)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qcontiguouscache.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h:46,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qdebug.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/math3d/qgenericmatrix.h:38,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qgenericmatrix.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/math3d/qquaternion.h:37,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qquaternion.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/math3d/qmatrix4x4.h:39,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qmatrix4x4.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/opengl/qopenglshaderprogram.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qopenglshaderprogram.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/QOpenGLShader:1,
                 from .moc/../opengl/qopenglengineshadermanager_p.h:217,
                 from .moc/moc_qopenglengineshadermanager_p.cpp:9:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qcontiguouscache.h:99:1: warning: this use of "defined" may not be portable [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
 #if QT_SUPPORTS(UNSHARABLE_CONTAINERS)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rm -f libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1 libQt5Gui.so libQt5Gui.so.5 libQt5Gui.so.5.5
g++ -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-O1 -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/opt/qt-5.5.1/lib -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,--dynamic-list,/home/cybex/qt5-5-1/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/src/gui/QtGui.dynlist -Wl,-soname,libQt5Gui.so.5 -o libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1 .obj/qimage_ssse3.o .obj/qdrawhelper_ssse3.o .obj/qimage_sse4.o .obj/qdrawhelper_sse4.o .obj/qimagescale_sse4.o .obj/qimage_avx2.o .obj/qdrawhelper_avx2.o .obj/qimage_compat.o .obj/qaccessible.o .obj/qaccessiblecache.o .obj/qaccessibleobject.o .obj/qaccessibleplugin.o .obj/qplatformaccessibility.o .obj/qaccessiblebridge.o .obj/qgenericpluginfactory.o .obj/qgenericplugin.o .obj/qwindowsysteminterface.o .obj/qplatforminputcontextfactory.o .obj/qplatforminputcontextplugin.o .obj/qplatforminputcontext.o .obj/qplatformintegration.o .obj/qplatformdrag.o .obj/qplatformscreen.o .obj/qplatformintegrationfactory.o .obj/qplatformintegrationplugin.o .obj/qplatformtheme.o .obj/qplatformthemefactory.o .obj/qplatformthemeplugin.o .obj/qplatformwindow.o .obj/qplatformoffscreensurface.o .obj/qplatformcursor.o .obj/qplatformclipboard.o .obj/qplatformnativeinterface.o .obj/qsessionmanager.o .obj/qshapedpixmapdndwindow.o .obj/qsimpledrag.o .obj/qsurfaceformat.o .obj/qguiapplication.o .obj/qwindow.o .obj/qoffscreensurface.o .obj/qplatformsurface.o .obj/qsurface.o .obj/qclipboard.o .obj/qcursor.o .obj/qdrag.o .obj/qdnd.o .obj/qevent.o .obj/qinputmethod.o .obj/qkeysequence.o .obj/qkeymapper.o .obj/qpalette.o .obj/qguivariant.o .obj/qscreen.o .obj/qshortcutmap.o .obj/qstylehints.o .obj/qtouchdevice.o .obj/qplatformsharedgraphicscache.o .obj/qplatformdialoghelper.o .obj/qplatformservices.o .obj/qplatformsystemtrayicon.o .obj/qplatformsessionmanager.o .obj/qplatformmenu.o .obj/qpixelformat.o .obj/qpaintdevicewindow.o .obj/qrasterwindow.o .obj/qplatformgraphicsbuffer.o .obj/qplatformgraphicsbufferhelper.o .obj/qinputdevicemanager.o .obj/qplatformopenglcontext.o .obj/qopenglcontext.o .obj/qopenglwindow.o .obj/qbitmap.o .obj/qimage.o .obj/qimage_conversions.o .obj/qimageiohandler.o .obj/qimagereader.o .obj/qimagewriter.o .obj/qpaintengine_pic.o .obj/qpicture.o .obj/qpictureformatplugin.o .obj/qpixmap.o .obj/qpixmapcache.o .obj/qplatformpixmap.o .obj/qmovie.o .obj/qpixmap_raster.o .obj/qpixmap_blitter.o .obj/qnativeimage.o .obj/qimagepixmapcleanuphooks.o .obj/qicon.o .obj/qiconloader.o .obj/qiconengine.o .obj/qiconengineplugin.o .obj/qbmphandler.o .obj/qppmhandler.o .obj/qxbmhandler.o .obj/qxpmhandler.o .obj/qpnghandler.o .obj/qfont.o .obj/qfontengine.o .obj/qfontsubset.o .obj/qfontmetrics.o .obj/qfontdatabase.o .obj/qtextengine.o .obj/qtextlayout.o .obj/qtextformat.o .obj/qtextobject.o .obj/qtextoption.o .obj/qfragmentmap.o .obj/qtextdocument.o .obj/qtextdocument_p.o .obj/qtexthtmlparser.o .obj/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.o .obj/qtextdocumentlayout.o .obj/qtextcursor.o .obj/qtextdocumentfragment.o .obj/qtextimagehandler.o .obj/qtexttable.o .obj/qtextlist.o .obj/qtextdocumentwriter.o .obj/qsyntaxhighlighter.o .obj/qcssparser.o .obj/qzip.o .obj/qtextodfwriter.o .obj/qstatictext.o .obj/qrawfont.o .obj/qglyphrun.o .obj/qdistancefield.o .obj/qfontengine_qpf2.o .obj/qplatformfontdatabase.o .obj/qharfbuzzng.o .obj/qbackingstore.o .obj/qbezier.o .obj/qblendfunctions.o .obj/qblittable.o .obj/qbrush.o .obj/qcolor.o .obj/qcolor_p.o .obj/qcosmeticstroker.o .obj/qcssutil.o .obj/qdrawhelper.o .obj/qemulationpaintengine.o .obj/qgammatables.o .obj/qgrayraster.o .obj/qimagescale.o .obj/qmatrix.o .obj/qmemrotate.o .obj/qoutlinemapper.o .obj/qpagedpaintdevice.o .obj/qpagelayout.o .obj/qpagesize.o .obj/qpaintdevice.o .obj/qpaintengine.o .obj/qpaintengineex.o .obj/qpaintengine_blitter.o .obj/qpaintengine_raster.o .obj/qpainter.o .obj/qpainterpath.o .obj/qpathclipper.o .obj/qpdf.o .obj/qpdfwriter.o .obj/qpen.o .obj/qpolygon.o .obj/qrasterizer.o .obj/qregion.o .obj/qstroker.o .obj/qtextureglyphcache.o .obj/qtransform.o .obj/qplatformbackingstore.o .obj/qpathsimplifier.o .obj/qdesktopservices.o .obj/qvalidator.o .obj/qgridlayoutengine.o .obj/qabstractlayoutstyleinfo.o .obj/qlayoutpolicy.o .obj/qgenericmatrix.o .obj/qmatrix4x4.o .obj/qquaternion.o .obj/qvector2d.o .obj/qvector3d.o .obj/qvector4d.o .obj/qopengl.o .obj/qopenglfunctions.o .obj/qopenglframebufferobject.o .obj/qopenglpaintdevice.o .obj/qopenglbuffer.o .obj/qopenglshaderprogram.o .obj/qopenglgradientcache.o .obj/qopengltexturecache.o .obj/qopenglengineshadermanager.o .obj/qopengl2pexvertexarray.o .obj/qopenglpaintengine.o .obj/qopenglcustomshaderstage.o .obj/qtriangulatingstroker.o .obj/qopengltextureglyphcache.o .obj/qtriangulator.o .obj/qopenglversionfunctions.o .obj/qopenglversionfunctionsfactory.o .obj/qopenglvertexarrayobject.o .obj/qopengldebug.o .obj/qopengltextureblitter.o .obj/qopengltexture.o .obj/qopengltexturehelper.o .obj/qopenglpixeltransferoptions.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_1_0.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_1_1.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_1_2.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_1_3.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_1_4.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_1_5.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_2_0.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_2_1.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_3_0.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_3_1.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_3_2_core.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_3_3_core.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_0_core.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_1_core.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_2_core.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_3_core.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_4_core.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_5_core.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_3_2_compatibility.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_3_3_compatibility.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_0_compatibility.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_1_compatibility.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_2_compatibility.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_3_compatibility.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_4_compatibility.o .obj/qopenglfunctions_4_5_compatibility.o .obj/qopengltimerquery.o .obj/qguivariantanimation.o .obj/qstandarditemmodel.o .obj/qimage_sse2.o .obj/qdrawhelper_sse2.o .obj/moc_qaccessible.o .obj/moc_qaccessiblecache_p.o .obj/moc_qaccessibleplugin.o .obj/moc_qaccessiblebridge.o .obj/moc_qgenericplugin.o .obj/moc_qplatforminputcontext.o .obj/moc_qplatforminputcontextplugin_p.o .obj/moc_qplatformintegrationplugin.o .obj/moc_qplatformthemeplugin.o .obj/moc_qplatformnativeinterface.o .obj/moc_qplatformmenu.o .obj/moc_qshapedpixmapdndwindow_p.o .obj/moc_qoffscreensurface.o .obj/moc_qclipboard.o .obj/moc_qdrag.o .obj/moc_qdnd_p.o .obj/moc_qevent.o .obj/moc_qkeysequence.o .obj/moc_qkeymapper_p.o .obj/moc_qpalette.o .obj/moc_qsessionmanager.o .obj/moc_qscreen.o .obj/moc_qstylehints.o .obj/moc_qtouchdevice.o .obj/moc_qplatformsharedgraphicscache.o .obj/moc_qplatformdialoghelper.o .obj/moc_qpaintdevicewindow.o .obj/moc_qrasterwindow.o .obj/moc_qplatformgraphicsbuffer.o .obj/moc_qinputdevicemanager_p.o .obj/moc_qopenglcontext.o .obj/moc_qopenglwindow.o .obj/moc_qimageiohandler.o .obj/moc_qpictureformatplugin.o .obj/moc_qiconengineplugin.o .obj/moc_qfont.o .obj/moc_qfontdatabase.o .obj/moc_qtextformat.o .obj/moc_qtextobject.o .obj/moc_qtextdocument.o .obj/moc_qtextimagehandler_p.o .obj/moc_qtexttable.o .obj/moc_qtextlist.o .obj/moc_qbrush.o .obj/moc_qpainter.o .obj/moc_qpdfwriter.o .obj/moc_qplatformbackingstore.o .obj/moc_qvalidator.o .obj/moc_qopenglshaderprogram.o .obj/moc_qopenglengineshadermanager_p.o .obj/moc_qopengltimerquery.o  -L/home/cybex/qt5-5-1/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/lib -lQt5Core -lpthread -lpng -lqtharfbuzzng -lz -lGL 
ln -s libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1 libQt5Gui.so
ln -s libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1 libQt5Gui.so.5
ln -s libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1 libQt5Gui.so.5.5
rm -f ../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1
mv -f libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1  ../../lib/ 
rm -f ../../lib/libQt5Gui.so
rm -f ../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
rm -f ../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.5
mv -f libQt5Gui.so ../../lib/ 
mv -f libQt5Gui.so.5 ../../lib/ 
mv -f libQt5Gui.so.5.5 ../../lib/ 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/cybex/qt5-5-1/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/src/gui'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/cybex/qt5-5-1/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:46: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cybex/qt5-5-1/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase'
make: *** [Makefile:73: module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

I left out most of the `make` output, but above is how it fails, any thoughts on this?

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks for taking the time to help [@ssbssa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983398/ssbssa). Here is the full output of the `make -j 8` (compiling Qt 5.5.1)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cybex-dev/qt5.5.1-build_archlinux/master/qt5-build-output-all

Comment: Do you need the option `-developer-build`, because I suspect it adds `-Werror` to the compile options.

Comment: @ssbssa please see update

Comment: There are now only warnings in the new output you shared, that means the error must have been earlier.

Comment: @ssbssa hi, thanks for the help. Please see **update 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have many of these errors:

```
ssl/qsslcertificate_openssl.cpp: In function ‘uint qHash(const QSslCertificate&, uint)’:
ssl/qsslcertificate_openssl.cpp:63:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘X509 {aka struct x509_st}’
         return qHashBits(x509->sha1_hash, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, seed);
                              ^~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/comp.h:16,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:47,
                 from ../../include/QtNetwork/5.5.1/QtNetwork/private/../../../../../src/network/ssl/qsslcontext_openssl_p.h:53,
                 from ../../include/QtNetwork/5.5.1/QtNetwork/private/qsslcontext_openssl_p.h:1,
                 from ssl/qsslsocket_p.h:55,
                 from ssl/qsslsocket_openssl_p.h:63,
                 from ssl/qsslsocket_openssl_symbols_p.h:64,
                 from ssl/qsslcertificate_openssl.cpp:35:
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:119:16: note: forward declaration of ‘X509 {aka struct x509_st}’
 typedef struct x509_st X509;
                ^~~~~~~
```

So you extracted openssl 1.0.2g into `/opt/lib/openssl/`, but there are other (newer?) openssl headers in `/usr/include`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35516953/1983398), specifying you openssl header directory explicitely (add `-I /opt/lib/openssl/include/openssl` should solve this.