# Qt 5.5.1 not compiling on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu, makefile, openssl, qmake

I need to compile Qt 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 and facing issues because of openssl.
The answer here didn't fix the problem for me: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390497/qt-5-5-1-compiling-on-archlinux-results-with-error-this-use-of-defined-may-no)

Here is what I did:

- download qt5.5.1
- download openssl from here [openssl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/libssl1.0-dev/1.0.2n-1ubuntu5) then extract the content to /opt/openssl1.0.2
- configure qt:

  OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/opt/openssl1.0.2/lib -lssl -lcrypto' ~/src/Qt/5.5.1/configure -prefix /opt/Qt-build/5.5.1 -confirm-license -opensource -system-sqlite -nomake examples -nomake tests -openssl-linked -I /opt/openssl1.0.2/include/openssl -L /opt/openssl1.0.2/lib
- run make

The problem seems to be that qt still uses my system openssl lib and not the one I want to link!

```
/usr/include/openssl/types.h:157:16: note: forward declaration of ‘X509’ {aka ‘struct x509_st’}
  157 | typedef struct x509_st X509;
      |                ^~~~~~~
/home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslkey_openssl.cpp: In member function ‘bool QSslKeyPrivate::fromEVP_PKEY(EVP_PKEY*)’:
/home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslkey_openssl.cpp:81:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘EVP_PKEY’ {aka ‘struct evp_pkey_st’}
   81 |     if (pkey->type == EVP_PKEY_RSA) {
      |             ^~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/comp.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:28,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/5.5.1/QtNetwork/private/../../../../../src/network/ssl/qsslcontext_openssl_p.h:53,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/5.5.1/QtNetwork/private/qsslcontext_openssl_p.h:1,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_p.h:55,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslkey_p.h:51,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslkey_openssl.cpp:36:
/usr/include/openssl/types.h:107:16: note: forward declaration of ‘EVP_PKEY’ {aka ‘struct evp_pkey_st’}
  107 | typedef struct evp_pkey_st EVP_PKEY;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslkey_openssl.cpp:87:48: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘RSA’ {aka ‘rsa_st’}
   87 |         memcpy(rsa, q_EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey), sizeof(RSA));
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslkey_openssl.cpp:91:18: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘EVP_PKEY’ {aka ‘struct evp_pkey_st’}
   91 |     else if (pkey->type == EVP_PKEY_DSA) {
      |                  ^~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/comp.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:28,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/5.5.1/QtNetwork/private/../../../../../src/network/ssl/qsslcontext_openssl_p.h:53,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/5.5.1/QtNetwork/private/qsslcontext_openssl_p.h:1,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_p.h:55,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslkey_p.h:51,
                 from /home/dev/src/Qt/5.5.1/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslkey_openssl.cpp:36:
/usr/include/openssl/types.h:107:16: note: forward declaration of ‘EVP_PKEY’ {aka ‘struct evp_pkey_st’}
  107 | typedef struct evp_pkey_st EVP_PKEY;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the system provided openssl devleopment package so the openssl headers are no longer in /usr/include. Qt can't do anything against this because /usr/include is a system wide include path which is included every time.

Comment: removing the libssl-dev package brought me this error when configuring Qt: OpenSSL support cannot be enabled due to functionality tests!