# Installation of Qt 4.8.7 in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: qt, ubuntu, installation, qt4

I am trying to install Qt 4.8.7 from source (https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7.tar.gz) in a virtual machine running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

[image: 0_1551842108100_Ubuntu Machine.PNG]

So the commands I follow are:

```
mkdir Qt
cd Qt
wget https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7.tar.gz
tar -xzf qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7.tar.gz
mv qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7 Qt-Source
cd Qt-Source
./configure
```

Then I choose the Open Source Edition, accept the terms of License. After that it displays:

```
Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.7
```

So ...

```
make
```

and I have the next error;

[image: 0_1551845738419_Capturaqt.PNG]

Another thing is that in the process of running make, there are a lot of errors like these:

[image: 0_1551845788905_Capturaqt2.PNG]

Could you help me? Please

Comment: maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488166/error-compiling-qt5-with-openssl-linked, I think it's the same type of error and the cause seems to be the version of the OpenSSL library

Comment: Why do even Qt uses OpenSLL?

Comment: Qt has a submodule called Qt Network that uses it: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtnetwork-module.html

Comment: ArchLinux offers the Qt4 package but to compile it uses several patches, for more information check: https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/qt4 https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/qt4

Comment: How do I disable Qt Nerwork or obtain the correct OpenSSL library?

Comment: ```-skip: invalid command-line switch
qtnetwork: unknown argument
```

Comment: I recommend you check the patches of archlinux (they are in a previous comment) to see what modification they have made in the source code so that it compiles with the latest version of openssl, bye

Answer (score 2):

eyllanesc,

I faced the same problem as you a few days ago. And after many tries I did it.

First of all, you'll need to install another gcc and g++ version elder (I choose 4.8 version).

Follow the instructions in this another answer:
[GCC & C++ alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version)

And edit the file:
mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -std=gnu++98 -fpermissive
QMAKE_LFLAGS            = -std=gnu++98 -fpermissive
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          = -std=gnu++98 -fpermissive
```

With these flags the compiler will use C++98 version. Like 
[Bart_Vandewoestyne solution.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/85225/building-qt-4-8-7-using-g-6-3-0-with-std-gnu-98-on-debian-9-2-1-stretch/3)

Then run:

```
./configure -opensource -nomake demos -nomake examples -nomake tests -debug-and-release -qt3support -no-openssl -no-webkit
make -jN
sudo make install
```

After the complete installation back the default gcc and g++ versions:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo mv g++ g++-4.8_
sudo ln -s g++-7 g++
sudo mv gcc gcc-4.8_
sudo ln -s gcc-7 gcc
```

And test:

```
gcc --version
g++ --version
```

Now it's time to compile some code. But, before this we need to unchanged the modifications on our mkspec:

```
cd /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/
nano qmake.conf
```

And comment the lines changed and back to the original configuration:

```
#QMAKE_CFLAGS           = -std=gnu++98 -fpermissive 
#QMAKE_LFLAGS           = -std=gnu++98 -fpermissive 
#QMAKE_CXXFLAGS         = -std=gnu++98 -fpermissive

QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -m64
QMAKE_LFLAGS            = -m64
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          = -m64
```

Now your change you *.pro file adding or change these lines:

```
QMAKE_CXX = g++-7
QMAKE_CC  = gcc-7
```

Let me know if it works. For me everything it's fine.